# Extract number and following text and create multiple new columns in R

Tags: r, text, dplyr

I have free-text data with numerous references to specific questions, and I'd like to organize it as shown below.

I'm able to create columns that note mentions of a certain topic (if the respondent references it by number), but I'd like a way to extract all of the text following the number, until another number is encountered.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)

# Data
df <- data.frame(comment = c("topic 1: this is fine. 4 this is fine too. #9 not so good", "1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this idea. 25 great idea 43 cool idea"))

# I can identify the mentions if a respondent specifies the number they are responding to
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(mention = map(str_extract_all(comment, "[0-9]+"), as.numeric)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(col = mention, names_sep = "_")

# Ideal output
df_ideal <- structure(list(comment = c("topic 1: this is fine. 4 this is fine too. #9 not so good", 
"1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this idea. 25 great idea 43 cool idea"
), mention_1 = c(1, 1), mention_2 = c(4, 17), mention_3 = c(9, 
25), mention_4 = c(NA, 43), comment_1 = c("1: this is fine.", 
"1 ok this is fine."), comment_2 = c("4 this is fine too.", "17 i do not like this idea."
), comment_3 = c("9 not so good", "25 great idea"), comment_4 = c(NA, 
"42 nice idea")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `strsplit` to split at one or more space (`\\s+`) that follows a dot (`\\.` - `.` - metacharacters are escaped), and precedes a digit or `#` (regex lookaround), then we loop over the output `list` with `lapply`, remove any characters that are not digits  (`\\D+`) from the start (`^`) of each of the string with `sub`, `rbind` the `list` elements and assign the 'comment_' columns  into the original dataset 'df'

```
df[paste0('comment_', 1:3)] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df$comment, 
      "(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=[0-9#])", perl = TRUE), function(x) sub("^\\D+", "", x)))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  comment                                                      mention_1 mention_2 mention_3 comment_1          comment_2                   comment_3    
  <chr>                                                            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>              <chr>                       <chr>        
1 topic 1: this is fine. 4 this is fine too. #9 not so good            1         4         9 1: this is fine.   4 this is fine too.         9 not so good
2 1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this idea. 25 great idea         1        17        25 1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this idea. 25 great idea
```

#### Update

If the `length` differ (as in the updated example), we can pad `NA` at the end based on the `max` `lengths` from the `list` to make the `list` elements equal in `length` before doing the `rbind`

```
lst1 <- lapply(strsplit(df$comment, 
   "(topic \\d+)(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+(?=[0-9#])", perl = TRUE), 
         function(x) sub("^\\D+", "", x))
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
df[paste0('comment_', seq_len(mx))] <- do.call(rbind,
           lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  comment                                                             mention_1 mention_2 mention_3 mention_4 comment_1          comment_2                 comment_3    comment_4  
  <chr>                                                                   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>              <chr>                     <chr>        <chr>      
1 topic 1: this is fine. 4 this is fine too. #9 not so good                   1         4         9        NA 1: this is fine.   4 this is fine too.       9 not so go… <NA>       
2 1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this idea. 25 great idea 43 co…         1        17        25        43 1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this id… 25 great id… 43 cool id…
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer, I always appreciate your quick and impressive solutions. This does work, but my data will have different numbers of responses. Some people might only respond to one question and others might respond to 10 different ones. So it's not working on my real data. I'm updating the example now.

Comment: I again very much appreciate your updated solution but it does not seem to work for me. As a note, I think you have to remove the parenthesis after `perl = TRUE`, but it still does not add on additional comment columns. I also tried `mx = max(length(lst1))` instead of `lengths`, to get 4 instead of 1L.

Comment: I did just update the post with a slightly modified reprex

Comment: @Matt In the update, are you also splitting at space not after `.`

Comment: yes, ideally the logic for splitting would be: "find a number (0 to 50 max) and any text that follows until another number is found"

Comment: Thanks! that works as well as I could have imagined. I really appreciate your help. I'll probably be back with another question soon...

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach is just to read the data in again:

```
read.table(text = gsub("(\\d+)","&\\1",df$comment), sep = "&", fill = TRUE,
           comment.char = "", header = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, na.strings = "")[,-1]
                  V2                          V3            V4           V5
1   1: this is fine.       4 this is fine too. # 9 not so good         <NA>
2 1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this idea. 25 great idea 43 cool idea
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue without your extract and `unnest_wider` approach.

```
library(tidyverse)


df %>%
  mutate(mention = map(str_extract_all(comment, "[0-9]+"), as.numeric), 
         new_comment = str_extract_all(comment, '\\d+.*?(?=\\d|$)')) %>%
  unnest_wider(col = new_comment, names_sep = "_") %>%
  unnest_wider(col = mention, names_sep = "_")

#                                                                    comment
#1                 topic 1: this is fine. 4 this is fine too. #9 not so good
#2 1 ok this is fine. 17 i do not like this idea. 25 great idea 43 cool idea

#  mention_1 mention_2 mention_3 mention_4       new_comment_1
#1         1         4         9        NA   1: this is fine. 
#2         1        17        25        43 1 ok this is fine. 

#                 new_comment_2  new_comment_3 new_comment_4
#1        4 this is fine too. #  9 not so good          <NA>
#2 17 i do not like this idea.  25 great idea   43 cool idea
```